# Preload CCMoveTo action

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I'm working on an 'application' with 'cocos2D', in which I use some 'actions', and for example a 'CCMoveTo' like this :

```
CGPoint destination;
destination.x = …;
destination.y = …;
CCMoveTo * MovementAnimation = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:myTimer position:destination];
[Sprite runAction:MovementAnimation];
```

But when I call this code, there is a little lag, which is really not cool. The lag is appearing when 'CCMoveTo' is working the first time on a 'CCSprite'.

This is why i was asking me if there is a way to preload this sort of actions ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: is that on a device ? what is 'little' ?

Comment: It is on device and simulator. It's only the first time, if I apply to a CCSprite two times the action, it doesn't lag. There is a little gap, visible

Comment: well, those 2 lines of code (CCMoveTo ctor and runAction) should take a small fraction of 1 ms. There must be something else going on during that specific update cycle which causes your app to miss a frame. To convince yourself, time them and CCLOG the time taken.

Comment: I'm really sure that this comes from those lines, there's a little gap when I made a new CCMoveTo action

Comment: Using the init method of CCMoveTo may change anything ?